# Azure function failing to deploy from PowerShell command line

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've been deploying my PowerShell Azure Function 'MyApp-UT' successfully for sometime now.  I recently created a new function in Azure named 'MyApp-PROD', but when I deploy the exact same code to this new function, I get the following error.

```
func azure functionapp publish MyApp-PROD          
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 8.78 KB [###############################################################################]
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 8.78 KB [###############################################################################]
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 8.78 KB [###############################################################################]
Error uploading archive (InternalServerError).
Server Response: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"ChangeSetId(prod) does not match 7124f41ebe2c40278a6c3b6e96271a7b, 'master' or 'HEAD'","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at Kudu.Core.SourceControl.NullRepository.GetChangeSet(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\SourceControl\\NullRepository.cs:line 73\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.FetchDeploymentManager.<PerformDeployment>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\FetchDeploymentManager.cs:line 235\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.FetchDeploymentManager.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<FetchDeploy>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\FetchDeploymentManager.cs:line 115\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Contracts.Infrastructure.LockExtensions.<LockOperationAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Contracts\\Infrastructure\\LockExtensions.cs:line 134\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.FetchDeploymentManager.<FetchDeploy>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\FetchDeploymentManager.cs:line 108\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<PushDeployAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 429\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<ZipPushDeploy>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 97\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

But switching back to MyApp-UT I'm able to deploy.

```
func azure functionapp publish MyApp-UT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 8.78 KB [###############################################################################]
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
```

There shouldn't be anything different between these two functions.  They're in different resource groups though.  I have equal access to both.  On thoughts on how to start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer because it took me 2+ days to figure it out.  Had to delete this `deployments` folder.  But I don't know why... sorry!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete the deployments folder, just delete the old deployments within this folder.

[image]